# Passing parameters to route

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have a view that shows me departments and one that shows me projects, I would like that when I click on *view activity* I can only view projects from that department, **at the moment when I click on see department it shows me all projects from all departments**, my code below:

***My Index.vue:**

```html
<td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap text-right text-sm leading-5 font-medium">
  <inertia-link
  :href="route('app:projectdepartment.index', department.id)"
  :class="[ route().current('app:projectdepartment.index') ? 'text-white bg-gray-900' : 'text-gray-300']" class="group mb-1 flex items-center px-6 py-2 text-sm leading-6 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
  {{ $trans('labels.view-activity') }}
  </inertia-link>
</td>
```

***My Controller:**

```php
  public function index(ProjectFilter $filters)
    {
        return Inertia::render('back/app/departments/index-department', [
            'filters'  => request()->all('visibility', 'status', 'search'),
            'users'    => User::orderBy('name')->get()->map->only(['uuid', 'name', 'email', 'avatar_url']),
            'departments' => Department::orderBy('name')->get(),
            'projects' => Project::with('teamMembers', 'user', 'tasks')
                ->filter($filters)
                ->accessible()
                ->latest()
                ->paginate(10)
                ->transform(function ($project) {
                    return [
                        'uuid'          => $project->uuid,
                        'name'          => $project->name,
                        'description'   => $project->description,
                        'department_id' => $project->department_id,
                        'status'        => $project->status,
                        'pending_tasks' => $project->tasks()->pending()->count(),
                        'days_left'     => $project->days_left,
                        'team_members'  => $project->teamMembers->transform(function ($user) {
                            return [
                                'name'       => $user->name,
                                'avatar_url' => $user->avatar_url,
                            ];
                        })
                    ];
                })
        ]);
    }
```

```js
<script>
    import VAppDefaultLayout from '@/views/back/app/layouts/default'
    import VCreateProjectModal from '@/views/back/app/departments/modal-department-create'
    import VEmptyView from '@/views/common/empty'
    import VDropdown from '@/components/dropdown'
    import VPagination from '@/components/pagination'
    import VAlert from '@/components/alert/alert'

    export default {
        metaInfo() {
            return {
                title: this.$trans("headings.projects"),
            }
        },

        props: {
            filters: {
                type: Object
            }
        },

        components: {
            VAppDefaultLayout,
            VEmptyView,
            VDropdown,
            VPagination,
            VAlert
        },

        data() {
            return {
                filtersForm: {
                    status: this.filters.status,
                    visibility: this.filters.visibility,
                    search: this.filters.search,
                    // department: this.filters.id,
                    // department_id: this.$page.department.id,
                }


            }
        },

        watch: {
            filtersForm: {
                deep: true,
                handler: _.throttle(function () {
                    let query = _.pickBy(this.filtersForm);
                    this.$inertia.replace(this.route('app:projects.index', Object.keys(query).length ? query : {remember: 'forget'}))
                }, 150)
            }
        },

        methods: {
            showCreateDepartmentModal() {
                this.$modal(VCreateProjectModal, {
                    users: this.$page.users
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you facing any error in console ?

Comment: Mmh never used `:href` for that. Try `:to`. Example: `:to="{ name: 'app:projectdepartment.index', params: { id: department.id } }"` (or whatever your id parameter name is). Otherwise yeah, show the console errors as well please, if any.

Comment: So, the problem is query related, right? Can you update the question with the query scopes? (filter, accessible)